# Как правильно создать список List< класс>

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Проблема в следующем, при создания списка во всех индексах остается последнее добавленное значение, например в цикле заполняем список из 10 проходов и во всех 10 полях списка последнее добавленное число. Вот мой класс:

```
public class Roll implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int Numbern;

    private int Rollnum;

    private Date Timer;

    public int getNumbern() {
        return Numbern;
    }

    public void setNumbern(int numbern)
    {
        Numbern = numbern;
    }

    public int getRollnum()
    {
        return Rollnum;
    }

    public void setRollnum(int rollnum)
    {
        Rollnum = rollnum;
    }

    public Date getTimer()
    {
        return Timer;
    }

    public void setTimer(Date timer)
    {
        Timer = timer;
    }

    public  Roll (){}

}
```

Вот реализация с дополнением и получением результата:

```
 Roll roll = new Roll();

 List<Roll> list = new List<Roll>();

 while (resultSets.next())
 {
  roll.setNumbern(resultSets.getInt(1)); 

  roll.setRollnum(resultSets.getInt(2));

  roll.setTimer(resultSets.getDate(3));

  list.add(roll);
  }

  System.out.println(list.get(0).getNumbern());
```

Что я делаю не правильно ? И как решить проблему ? Пробовал и LinkedList результат тот же если попала 1-ца в 10-й то и все 1-10 полей будут 1-ца

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создавайте новый объект Roll на каждой итерации цикла.
Иначе вы последовательно 10 раз записываете данные в один и тот же объект, поэтому в нем останутся только данные последней итерации.
Попробуйте так:

```
 List<Roll> list = new List<Roll>();

 while (resultSets.next())
 {
  Roll roll = new Roll();

  roll.setNumbern(resultSets.getInt(1)); 

  roll.setRollnum(resultSets.getInt(2));

  roll.setTimer(resultSets.getDate(3));

  list.add(roll);
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Просто в C# немного иначе.

Comment: @Ethernets, успехов!)

Comment: @Ethernets В C# вообще-то точно так же. Ты классы со структурами путаешь.

Comment: @Alex78191 разве ? По-моему в С# создание объекта разрешено вне цикла. Завтра проведу тест возможно я действительно не прав. Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: @Ethernets так и в Java проблем при создании у тебя не было, но массив будет состоять из одинаковых обеъктов будет как и в C#. Я уже [провел](https://ideone.com/GS947t) тестирование.

Answer (score 3):

Объект Roll надо пересоздавать на каждой итерации цикла, тогда все будет ок. Посмотри как устроены ссылочные типы данных и станет понятнее почему так работает.

Comment: постарайтесь дать более развернутый ответ, желательно с примерами, тогда ваши ответы будут оценены и вознаграждены

Comment: @Артем Асташов Вам тоже спасибо за ответ, поставлю + за старание и за помощь.